# How to get image src by class

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I have this:

```
<a href="/Dealer-Catalog/ManufacturerID-3">[![ADTRAN][1]][1]
```

how to get img src (http://www.teledynamics.com/tdresources/74c42cb2-dc7f-4548-b820-2946fbe160db.jpg)

I tried a lot of things and that was the last one:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//class='brand-logo']/img/@src)");
echo "$src";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not proper XPath syntax. Try

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//img[@class='brand-logo']");
$src = $nodes->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

First you fetch the NODE that represents the image whose src you want, THEN you get the src attribute. Note that the ->query() call returns a DOMNodeList, not a node.

Comment: Try changing `$nodes[0]` to `$nodes->item( 0)`?

Comment: @MarcB: Pull it in one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603722/367456 - (as you already do xpath here)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
    <?php
    $html = '<a href="/Dealer-Catalog/ManufacturerID-3">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="http://www.teledynamics.com/tdresources/74c42cb2-dc7f-4548-b820-2946fbe160db.jpg"  alt="ADTRAN" />
        </a>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
    echo $xml->img['src'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<?php 
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="/Dealer-Catalog/ManufacturerID-3">
        <img class="brand-logo" src="http://www.teledynamics.com/tdresources/74c42cb2-dc7f-4548-b820-2946fbe160db.jpg"  alt="ADTRAN" />
        </a>');
$xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
$images=$xml->xpath('//img');
foreach ($images as $img) {
    echo $img['src'];


}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With xpath you can query an attribute directly, `string()` give it's node-value:

```
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img[@class='brand-logo']/@src)");
```

However I'm *really sorry* to say that I have no clue how that could be done with `preg_match` in your case ;)

Comment: i need preg_match to get this element from page cuz there are many link and images, but nvm its solved now, thanks anyway :)